# Unity 5.5.0f3 not running on Windows 11

Tags: unity-game-engine

I can't run Unity 5.5.0f3 on Windows 11 Pro 23H2, but Unity 5.6.7f1 works well.

When I try to start it, I see the loading banner, it disappears and the loading ends, it doesn’t reach the logs, since they are empty. Can anyone explain to me how I can run Unity 5.5.0f3 on Windows 11, please help.

Comment: Unity 5 is rather old these days. Probably doesn't support modern DirectX or environments well enough. Why are you using such an old version?

Comment: can you not still run things in compatibility mode (windows 11 machine turned off atm to check)